# Who (else) dislikes rights?

Tags: ethics, rights

I continually run across arguments where people fail to understand that morality is not **always and automatically** about **rights** *per se*, and particularly not necessarily about the intellectual equivalent of **legal** rights, which immediately create contradictions and presume an adversarial stance for their resolution.

What schools of philosophy have criticised 'rights' as an inadequate moral or political framing, and what are the best approaches those alternatives suggest for framing moral interaction?

I would like to avoid framings obsessed with conflict and control, since I think this is the most counterproductive aspect of most rights-talk.  But any clear alternative framework would be interesting.

---

To forestall further attempts to explain rights to me, I have an understanding of their purpose and use, which you are probably not going to talk me out of.

In my picture of the world, rights are a completely secondary manipulation to get people to act morally.  They simplify the communication of moral intent, but they have nothing, intrinsically, to do with what is or is not moral.  That needs to be established by some other underlying perspective.

If you have the right to raise your children as you wish, that does not mean all ways of raising children are equally moral.  Your right to free speech does not mean that whatever you say to me is never evil, and you have no moral reason to be civil.  In such situations, rights are an excuse to look no further, and a barrier to genuine ethical inquiry.

Also as a manipulation, they have to be open about their intent, which they never are.  People retrench into their own sense of their own rights as if they are the actual content of the ethics.  So they do not realize when their defensive position contradicts the moral motivation for the right itself.

Comment: I wouldn't choose to dislike or like rights. I like to look at this way. Rights are like a set of rules. Rules are restrictive. If not obeyed, punishedment is layed upon. It is extra motivation to behave a certain way. Some communities require rules (restrictions) or otherwise they fall apart in chaos. (Childeren in kindergarten e.g.) Only mature enough communities can have fewer rights (rules=restrictions) as the members know AND feel how to behave. So in that sense, I even think that rights (e.g. human rights) is a good thing on the path of growing our worldwide community.

Comment: @mike de Klerk: the crux of the question is suggesting that morality or ethics is not *always* and *solely* about rights.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I understand that. I was aiming at the title of OPs question. I was trying to add some nuance to it. I know its off-topic to OPs question.

Comment: One often has the right to act immorally.  Decisions about what to say can be very morally complex, while the right to free speech is relatively simple, so it's clear that morality encompasses more than rights.  Rights exist in order to allow individuals as much freedom as possible in making moral choices, without reducing other's ability to do the same.  They're very important, but they are a consequent of morality, not a primary.

Comment: I think what you and people in the West refer to as human rights are individual rights - which is a Western conceptualization of rights. In the East, most people (and societies consequently) see societal rights as human rights and are of greater importance than individual rights.

Answer (score 4):

Alasdair MacIntyre is a famous critic of rights. See his book "After Virtue":

> The truth is plain: there are no such [i.e. human] rights, and belief in them is one with belief in witches and unicorns.
>
> The best reason for asserting so bluntly that there are no such rights is indeed of precisely the same type as the best reason we have for asserting that there are no witches and the best reason we have for asserting that there are no unicorns: every attempt to believe that there *are* such rights has failed.  (p. 69)

To evaluate the cogency of MacIntyre's claim goes beyond what can be done in an SE answer--you'd need to read his account of those attempts and decide for yourself whether his negative evaluation is warranted.

**edit: also generally marxist theorists are critical of human rights discourse, seeing it as a bourgeois ruse to deny equality to the proletariat.**

Comment: In your edit, are you talking about real marxists? Or so-called postmodernists?

Comment: I mean people like Chairman Mao. If he’s not a real Marxist, I don’t know who is. I don’t have a citation from Marx himself though.

Comment: Have you read Mao's Red Book or any other? Where is Mao saying he is critical of human rights discourse?

Comment: http://digitalcommons.law.umaryland.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1093&context=mscas starting on page 3, describes various official statements from ministers of Mao’s administration denouncing “human rights” as capitalist/imperialist justifications for interfering with the internal affairs (i.e. annexation of tibet, or the intentional starvation, brutalization, and repression of its own people) of socialist states. More to the point, do you really think of the man who presided over the state sponsored genocide of 45 million of his own people as a proponent of human rights?

Comment: Do you know the difference between genocide and hunger caused by errors when trying to centralize an economy in a country with more than a billion people? Most people that love to paint Mao as "the enemy" or as "a monster" don't know, or pretend they don't know. Annexation of Tibet? Right, so if England had colonized only Ireland, then I think both would be at the same level. But they're obviously not. So Europe colonized half the world, stole all our gold, enslaved thousands of peoples, and today live large on its profits, and want to accuse others of "human rights violations"? Don't kid me!

Comment: http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/news/maos-great-leap-forward-killed-45-million-in-four-years-2081630.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_famines. Look how many times China appears on the list, and how many deaths each time (look the years when each happened too). Want to know what kind of man was Mao Zedong? Read his Red Book. Trying to understand him from what the English say of him is like trying to understand Christ from what Muslims say of him, right?

Comment: It’s not the /famine/ per se that’s objectionable: it’s making the father of a starving boy who stole a handful of rice bury his child alive that I can’t get over. In a time of famine you might have to ration; but I find it objectionable that mao’s government refused to give those rations to the elderly or infirm on the grounds that these were not workers capable of supporting the state. I don’t judge Mao’s character by the ideals expressed in his propaganda; I judge his character by his actions and policy.

Comment: Or at least from what you heard about them. Still, he was acting based on the customs of his people. Some peoples are cannibals who eat the ashes of its best warriors. Catholics will say that this is barbaric, but will send to jail a father because he was smoking an herb he himself planted, that humankind smokes for thousands of years now (and which the sons of lawyers and judges love to smoke -- unpunished). Yes, when "human rights" is used to denounce the errors of others, but not our own, then it has become a weapon of soft power.

Comment: @Rodrigo I said marxists are suspicious of human right language. You denied this. I cited the sources.  Now you are evincing the *the very suspicion of human rights talk* that I said marxists held and for exactly the same reason! Look I don’t like rights language either—for basically MacIntyre’s reasons. But if you want to say my characterization of Marxism is inaccurate because Marxists do believe in rights, then you can’t go on in the next breath and say that rights talk is just an instrument of western imperialism. You can’t have it both ways.

Comment: I'm not saying that rights are "just an instrument of western imperialism". I'm saying that Westerners in general love to denounce supposed rights violation just to advance with their own rights violation. They disagree with China imposing a one-child policy ("that's against people's rights!"), pretending they ignore the problem of Chinese overpopulation. They disagree that the Communist Party don't let Western media flow freely in China ("that's against freedom of information!"), pretending they ignore that Western media has its own interests and ways of brainwashing.

Comment: If you read philosophers that are not bulldogs of Western imperialism, and thus are able to compare the different cultures in a more impartial way (I can think of Voltaire, Bertrand Russell, John Gray...), you'll see that the Chinese are not barbarians who kill children for nothing, like those bulldogs like to paint them. If you still read the basis of Chinese culture, then you'll understand how Christians, Jews and Muslims are the real barbarians.

Comment: This is preposterous. I have nothing more to say to you.

Comment: You should not say. You should analyze and think.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Simone Weil and Alasdair MacIntyre (and communitarians in general), we could add two further types of critiques:

1. Confucians and Chinese philosophy more generally. The volume *Confucian Ethics* edited Kwong-loi Shun and David Wong contains several articles that spell out Confucian objections to rights talk. More broadly, rights talk is not a feature of any classical school of Chinese philosophy or thought.
2. Plato. Rights are not a major feature in his account of the polis.

It's a little fuzzier for pre-Modern thinkers in general for that matter. While some speak of rights, the idea of universal human rights does not become a major concept in *ethics* until much later, having a strong origin in *law* in the Medieval and Roman traditions. But even in those, it's not entirely clear if they mean something like the modern notion that people just have rights rather than meaning something like rights in virtue of title or ownership.

for one obvious example, the *Magna Carta*, while clearly invaluable in the genealogy of rights, is about the rights of a certain class of nobles against King John rather than a document granting everyone rights. And it's a document that has legal force in part due to the complex interactions of states and the Roman Catholic Church at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Simone Weil was a critic of the notion of rights in her essay on *The Human Personality*; she wrote:

> The notion of rights, which was launched on the world on 1789, has proved unable, because of intrinsic inadequacy, to fulfil the role assigned to it.

For:

> The notion of rights is linked with sharing out, of exchange, of measured quantity. It has a commercial flavour, essentially of a legal claims and arguments. Rights are always asserted in a tone of contention; and when this tone is adopted, it must rely on force in the background, otherwise it will be laughed at.

Against the notion of right, which she notes originates from Roman law (and is personal); she compares the Greek notion of justice (which is impersonal).

To put this in colloquial but aphoristic terms: justice is the spirit of the law and not its letter; rights are the letter of the law and not its spirit.

To connect this Weils above; note that the letter can be measured - it is written; and the spirit cannot - it is unwritten.

It's this dialectic that informs Sophocles *Antigone*; she standing for the the unlettered custom, ie positive law; and Creon, for sovereign law.

Another way of thinking through this concept is through Schmitts definition of sovereignty in his *Political Theology* where he securalises a theological concept of sovereignty:

> Sovereign is he who decides on the *exception*

One can then ask what is that decides the exception - the exceptional case - that in some part lies outside that of the written law; it cannot be the law itself - thus it would be Justice; there is then a scale of values in which Justice stands above that of Rights; it is sovereign, and cannot be assimilated to it.